# Why single tap confirmed is called at first instead of double tap?

Tags: android, touch-event

Actually I'm trying to perform two operations with `singleTapConfirmed()` and `doubleTap()`.For this I'm using `GestureTap` class which extends from `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener` . Although it's working fine for some devices but in some devices like `nougat` and `oreo` it's receiving `singleTapConfirmed()` first even by **doubleTap**. I wonder how to fix this issue.

Code:

```
class GestureTap extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    private Context ctx;
        public GestureTap(Context ctx) {
            this.ctx = ctx;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
       Toast.makeText(ctx, ”Double Tap”, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
     Toast.makeText(ctx, ”Single Tap”, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The system double tap timeout is ViewConfiguration.getDoubleTapTimeout(); I am not sure the delay in tapping might be triggering both,check this once.

Comment: @AjgTheta sir how to do that

Comment: check the post for answer

Answer (score 2):

This might help you,

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getActionMasked();
                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    final long now = event.getEventTime();
                    if (now - mTouchTime < ViewConfiguration.getDoubleTapTimeout()) {
                        mTouchTime = 0;
                        //doubleClick(event);
                    } else {
                        mTouchTime = now;
                    }
                } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) {
                    mTouchTime = 0; // no double-tap for other fingers
                }

            return true;
    }
```

Comment: great thanks for your answer . Although now double tap is received properly but how get singleTapConfirmed